# Replacing a Spring bean that have Autowired dependency during testing

Tags: spring, inversion-of-control, javabeans, autowired, applicationcontext

I am trying to get Spring to replace a class that has autowired dependencies with another (test class) that do not have these autowire dependencies, but I always end up with a NoSuchBeanDefinitionException like this:

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.experiments.beanreplacement.client.Connection' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

I have created a simplifed example to show my problem.

I have two classes in my client package (Connection.java and TcpClient.java) and two in my application package (MessageSender.java and Scheduler.java)

```
package com.experiments.beanreplacement.client;
@Component
public class Connection {
    public void send(String msg) { System.out.println("Connection send: " + msg); }
...
```

The TcpClient.java autowires the Connection class:

```
@Component
public class TcpClient {

    @Autowired
    Connection connection;

    public void send(String msg) {
        System.out.println("TcpClient send");
        connection.send(START_OF_MESSAGE + msg + END_OF_MESSAGE);
   }
}
```

The MessageSender class use the TcpClient to send messages:

```
package com.experiments.beanreplacement.application;    
@Component
public class MessageSender {
    @Autowired
    TcpClient client;

    public void sendAMessage() {
        client.send("Hello world!");
        client.send("Bye bye...");
    }
}
```

I have set up a test to run this using JUnit:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"/applicationContext.xml"})
public class MessageSenderTest {

    @Autowired
    MessageSender messageSender;

    @Test
    public void testMessageSender() {
        messageSender.sendAMessage();
    }
}
```

TcpClientMock class:

```
package client;
@Primary
public class TcpClientMock extends com.experiments.beanreplacement.client.TcpClient{
    @Override
    public void send(String msg) {
        System.out.println("Mock client send: " + msg);
    }
    ...
```

applicationContext.xml

```
    <bean class="client.TcpClientMock" name="client" >
    </bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.experiments.beanreplacement.application">
    </context:component-scan>
    ...
```

In the applicationContext.xml file, I replace the TcpClient which is autowired in the MessageSender class with another (TcpClientMock).

I have adjusted the component-scan to only look at the path of the MessageSender and TcpClientMock, hoping to avoid having to deal with the autowire dependencies of the original TcpClient and underlying Connection.

However, I still get the "No qualifying bean of type 'com.experiments.beanreplacement.client.Connection' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate." error even though the class using the autowire dependency is not part of the component-scan.

Is there a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to Mock your `TcpClient` bean with @MockBean. In you test add:

```
@MockBean
TcpClient client;
```

in your test method you can specify the behavior of the `send()` method like so:

```
String msg = "anything";
doAnswer(i -> {
                System.out.println("Mock client send: " + msg);
                return null;
            }
    ).when(client).send(msg);
```